# Trigger/Modify Browser ScrollIntoView Behavior on Focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, focus

I have a scrollable table with a sticky header & footer, and input fields in each cell - think an Exel-like table. Now I encountered a problem when using tab to focus input fields in a row further down. Normally, the browser automatically scrolls inputs into view on focus. It does that normally most of the time. However, if the input element is exactly behind the sticky header or footer, then it gets treated as "in view" and no scrolling happens, at least in Firefox.

Now my question is: Can I somehow tell the browser to treat the elements behind the header/footer as invisible, and scroll when focusing them, or do I have to reproduce the behavior manually for these elements? And if the latter is the case: How can I exactly reproduce this? Using `scrollIntoView()` does not behave identical, for example also scrolling any parent containers to position the element relative to the viewport, instead of just scrolling enough to make it visible.

[Simple Example on Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Tried `scrollIntoView`, but it behaves differently to browser scroll on focus.